# Install cypress on aws Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, cypress

I want to install cypress on AWS lambda for performing testcases. I have explored the internet but none of the solutions are working for me like storage issues of lambda etc. Can anyone give me a reference about this? Thank you in Advance.

Comment: This article discusses in detail on how you can setup and run cypress tests in AWS lamda - https://stuartsandine.com/cypress-on-aws-lambda-part-1/

Comment: I have tried it but many of those things involved there have been deprecated and it's not mainatained

Comment: I am currently trying to install using [Deploy container images on aws lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/) hope it helps others.

Comment: Hi @SridharRaju, how is this going? I come with the same requirement to run cypress in aws lambda. If got any idea, please update

Comment: Not done yet, currently working on other tasks

Answer (score 2):

In order to get cypress running on AWS lambda, there are a few issues that you need to work through.

[I've put together a full minimal example of how to get cypress running on lambda.](https://github.com/magJ/cypress-lambda-example)

I'll cover the highlights of what is involved.

Lambda runs with a read-only file system, using an unprivileged user, and no ipc or shared memory device.

The only writable location is the `/tmp` directory, which has 512mb of space by default.

- Cypress needs to be installed at a location that is readable by non-privileged users.
- In order to get electron to work, it's binary needs to be patched so it doesn't try and use `/dev/shm`
- Cypress requires that project directory is writable, which means that you need to copy the project into the `/tmp` directory, or patch cypress so it won't crash.
- We need to pass a bunch of flags to chromium, to disable features that use things like GPU, and shared memory, which aren't available on lambda.

Comment: Is it in working condition or do you still need to make any changes?

Comment: @Msvstl The example code works as-is.